Seeking a special combination of two functions under certain conditions
I want a combination h(x), of any two general functions f(x) and g(x) such that:

h(x)=0 if and only if f(x) and g(x) intercept the x axis at the same x value.
The x intercepts of h(x) are always points in which h(x) passes through the x axis (switches signs).
f(x) and g(x) cannot be 0 for all x on a continuous interval of x values.

I've tried h(x)=f(x)+g(x), h(x)=|f(x)|+|g(x)|, and many others. I always find a pair of functions f(x) and g(x) that don't meet one of those requirements.
Thank you all.
